# Citation Style Language (CSL) style for resume / CV

Tags: cv, citation-style

I have my own publications on Zotero, and would like a convenient way to export these references directly to my resume/CV so I only have to update them once. Is there a CSL style that can generate resume-style publication lists? They should appear in the following format and be sorted in reverse chronological order:

```
2020  Full bibliographic reference, formatted
      in whatever sensible style can be found.
```

Comment: I am not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for, but I made a LaTeX CV template a while ago which takes a .bib file as your publication lists and outputs it in reversed chronological order: https://github.com/Thijsvanede/cv . It is just something I use for my own CV, but feel free to use it for yours as well

Comment: Thanks! That's an interesting way to solve the problem. Though it's not exactly my use case (I have my CV in markdown ad process it with Pandoc and Pandoc-citeproc, hence the need for CSL), I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam Altmejd's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/adamaltmejd/cv) has a CSL file that seems to be what you are looking for. Adam also compiles his CV from markdown with BibTeX via Pandoc and Pandoc-citeproc.

Comment: This seems to work! I might pick up from there and see if I can generate a reverse-chronological bibliography.

Answer (score 0):

Most citation manager allow you to change styles/define custom styles. [For zotero see here](https://www.zotero.org/support/dev/citation_styles/style_editing_step-by-step).

All you need to do then is make a document where you add citations to all your references in whatever order you want, add the bibliography and copy it to your CV.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the easiest solution will be using the [APA-CV citation style](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles-distribution/blob/master/apa-cv.csl) as proposed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58907768/14993291).